# Issue mapping many to many relationship using EF Core fluent mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to determine how to provide fluent configuration mappings for the below data model:

Entities:

- `Product`
- `Set`
- `Attribute`

Relationship requirements:

- Each Product has 1 Set
- Each Set has one or more Attributes
- Each Attribute can belong to one or more sets

So, based on this, I have the following:

- `Product (1...*) Set`
- `Set (*...*) Attribute`
  (This is represented by a join table `SetAttribute`) as follows:

`SetAttribute`:

- `AttributeId` (FK,PK)
- `AttributeSetId` (FK,PK)
- `ProductId` (FK,PK)
- `Value`

EF Core will not allow me to set the following mapping configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Set>()
   .HasMany(x => x.Attributes)
   .WithMany(x => x.Sets)
   .UsingEntity<SetAttribute>(
       j => j.HasOne(sa => sa.Attribute)
             .WithMany(x => x.SetAttributes)   
             .HasForeignKey(sa => sa.AttributeId),
       j => j.HasOne(sa => sa.Set)
             .WithMany(x => x.SetAttributes)
             .HasForeignKey(sa => sa.SetId),
       j => j.HasOne(sa => sa.Product)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(sa => sa.ProductId),
       j =>
       {
           j.HasKey(x => new {x.SetId, x.AttributeId, x.ProductId});
           j.Property(x => x.Value);
       });
```

I get an error:

> Cannot convert anonymous method block to delegate type 'delegate type' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: There is something confusing. Each product has one set then now it is one to many. It is one to one relation. Same way set has attributes but are you sharing same attribute with multiple set or each set has its own attribute ?

Comment: Hi @dotnetstep. So, attributes are shared across sets. So each set can have the same attributes, but with a different value. So if `Brand` is an attribute, and say `Phones` and `Tablets` are 2 Sets then Brand can be part of both these Sets, and will have a different value for each Product. So, if I add `IPhone11` and `Samsung Galaxy` as Products, both within Set `Phones` the Brand attribute value will be different